# AD server connect error (LDAP) about ETIMEOUT

Tags: node.js, active-directory, ldap

I am connecting AD server using Node JS package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory2).
But I can't connect to AD server, always it return error

> ERROR: {"errno":-4039,"code":"ETIMEDOUT","syscall":"connect","address":"Some IP here","port":389}

My code looks like this

```
const config = { 
  url: 'LDAP://Mydomain.com',
  baseDN: 'dc=Mydomain,dc=com', 
}
const ad = new AD(config);
const username = 'myuser';

await ad.userExists(username, function(err, exists) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
    return null;
  }
 
  console.log(username + ' exists: ' + exists);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by connecting to the same network where ldap is hosted.

I also need to mention that I had a vpn access but the ldap service was not added and that is why I got this error.

Try to do the same, I am sure it is related to the network because when I changed the config options to enter random urls it was giving me a different error.

> Error:
> {"errno":-3008,"code":"ENOTFOUND","syscall":"getaddrinfo","hostname":"*"}